# Amateur Radio CS750 driver question

Tags: drivers, usb

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am attempting to program a DMR amateur radio, a [Connect Systems CS750](http://www.connectsystems.com/products/top/radios%20CS750.htm).

But the program does not recognize my STMicroElectronics driver.
I get a message that the USB is not connected or recognized.

Using the `lsusb` terminal command, I see the device on `Bus 002 dev 005`.
Any ideas how to get the device recognized?

Comment: Post results from `lsusb`  Where did you get the driver from?

Comment: In a terminal window, execute `journalctl --follow` to watch ongoing log messages, then plug in your device. Or, see the last 10 minutes of logs with `journalctl  --since "$(date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --date="now - 10 minutes")"`

Comment: which porgram are you useing